# How to login using e-mail in ASP.NET Identity 2.0 alpha 1?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

[ASP.NET Identity 2.0 alpha 1 has been released](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx&ei=LwcEU5PfMo-LkAey5oDAAg&usg=AFQjCNHna9vcLUCiHWualAjuoqL34V7KWA&sig2=MrAdyw-MW-VWEHiZFQPhnQ) and they introduced `Email` in the `IdentityUser<>` class. Nice!

The problem is that I still cannot login using the e-mail address, apparently. The `UserManager` class has a `FindByEmail` method but it will not take the password as a parameter, and the `VerifyPassword` method is protected, so I just cannot verify the user identity using e-mail instead of user name.

Any way I can make this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to do this in 2.0.0 RTM with a new CheckPassword(TUser, string password) method.  For now, you can use Email as the user name, or you can have to add your own method to UserManager to expose a check email/password method.